# Thread context switching in program output using Pthread library

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am currently studying multi-threading and Pthread. I have written a sequence program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void foo(){
  
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
       printf("Hello world from foo\n");
   }
  
}
void foo1(){
 
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
       printf("Hello world from foo1\n");
   }
   
}

void bar(){
  
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
       printf("Hello world from bar\n");
   }
}

int main(){
  
    foo();
    foo1();
    bar();
   
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
       printf("Hello world from main\n");
    }


}
```

Obviously, the output of this program is the same all time:

```
Hello world from foo
Hello world from foo
Hello world from foo
Hello world from foo1
Hello world from foo1
Hello world from foo1
Hello world from bar
Hello world from bar
Hello world from main
Hello world from main
```

When I modified the source code using Pthread, the output became chaotic sometimes. Here are my modified code and an example output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* foo(){
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
       printf("Hello world from foo\n");
   }
}
void* foo1(){
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
       printf("Hello world from foo1\n");
   }
}

void bar(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
       printf("Hello world from bar\n");
   }
}

int main(){
  
    pthread_t t1,t2;

    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,foo,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,foo1,NULL);
    
    bar();
    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);
   
   
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
       printf("Hello world from main\n");
    }


}
```

```
Hello world from foo
Hello world from foo
Hello world from foo
Hello world from bar
Hello world from foo1
Hello world from foo1
Hello world from foo1
Hello world from bar
Hello world from main
Hello world from main
```

As we can see from the output above, the order of print function in bar function doesn't happen continually. I guess it might be affected by thread context-switching in thread scheduling.
Is my thought about this issue right?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: *it might be affected by thread context-switching in thread scheduling*. Yes that is the case. There are essentially three threads and the exact order of execution is determined by the scheduler.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In this example, I used print function to present the program output. Therefore, context switching becomes more clear. I mean if we perform some calculation tasks, it's hard to realize it.
What's will happen if we create threads for tasks that have data dependency? Suppose we create 2 threads for functions A and B. Functions B will wait for the result of A to execute. In multi-threading theory, multiple threads can execute concurrently. But in this case, B needs to wait for A. How does OS handle this situation?

Comment: OS doesn't handle. It's your job as the programmer to handle it. The OS gives you synchronisation mechanisms such as semaphores which you can use to code up the desired multi threaded behaviour.

Comment: That is the reason why multi-threading is always a challenge to programmers, isn't it? We need to reserve the correction of the program while deciding which part of the program should create a new thread to boost the performance.

Comment: Yes. It is a challenge, but the performance benefits makes us go towards multithreading. With multicore processors, it is more important to make use of multi-threading. Most of the applications that you would use on your PC or phone today use multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. There are three threads that are being executed and it is up to the scheduler of your operating system to schedule the threads and perform context switching. Hence, you may not get the same output each time you run this code

Comment: Thanks for your help. In this example, I used print function to present the program output. Therefore, context switching becomes more clear. I mean if we perform some calculation tasks, it's hard to realize it.
What's will happen if we create threads for tasks that have data dependency? Suppose we create 2 threads for functions A and B. Functions B will wait for the result of A to execute. In multi-threading theory, multiple threads can execute concurrently. But in this case, B needs to wait for A. How does OS handle this situation?

Comment: That's the application programmer's task to handle this situation. There are many synchronisation functions available to help the application programmer get the desired behaviour. In this case, the join function does that job